Proof of necessity for uniform Wick rotation
This may be a subtle question, but a satisfying answer is one I have yet to find.
Consider the vacuum expectation value of some physical observable $\langle \Omega|\hat{\phi}(x_1)\cdots\hat{\phi}(x_n)|\Omega\rangle$. Suppose that I am working in the path integral formulation of quantum field theory, and I want to ensure the convergence of the path integral by analytically continuing the time-component of each operator $x_1^0,x_2^0,\dots x_n^0$. To ensure analyticity, I impose by hand a specific ordering of imaginary time
\begin{equation}
\text{Im}\:x_1^0<\text{Im}\:x_2^0<\cdots<\text{Im}\:x_n^0.
\end{equation}
First question: is this put in by hand, or is there a better argument here to be made for ensuring analyticity of the path integral?
The real parts of the time components are not subject to any ordering a priori. The contour taken through the imaginary time components can be $C$ with the action written as $S = \int_C dx^0\int d^{D-1}\mathbf{x}\:\mathcal{L}$.
Ok, now suppose I already start with the Euclidean correlator
\begin{equation}
\langle\hat{\phi}_E(x_1^E)\dots\hat{\phi}_E(x_n^E)\rangle
\end{equation}
where $(x_1^E)^D>\cdots>(x_n^E)^D$, and perform a general Wick rotation $-ix^0_i = e^{-i\alpha}t_i$ for every Euclidean time component.
Question two: why is it that ensure $\alpha = \pi/2$ maintains the ordering of $\text{Im}\: x_i^0$? Or, in the limit that $\alpha\rightarrow 0^+$, we then have a real time correlator that is time-ordered i.e. $x_1^0<\cdots x_n^0$? Another way to phrase all of my confusion is, why is a uniform Wick rotation on all $x_i^0$'s necessary in order to obtain the time-ordered real-time correlator from the Euclidean on?
I think a graph (hand drawn or not) would help a great deal in my case. For example, why would happen if we arbitrarily Wick rotated every time coordinate as $-ix_i^0 = e^{-i\alpha_i}t_i$ where there is now an $\alpha_i$ for every $x_i^0$? It seems to me that one possible explanation is that if there was a differing $\alpha_i$ for every $x_i^0$, then time-ordering in real-time could not hold true, and a version of causality (I think this is ok to say) is lost. Could this be made into a contour argument?
EDIT: Another question I forgot to add is, why do we only analytically continue the (with reference to the corresponding Feynman diagram) external momenta and not the internal momenta? Is this a weird thing to ask and does not correspond to anything?
